# A question on magic square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, magic-square

A magic square of order $N$ is an $N\times N$ matrix with positive integral entries such that the elements of every row, every collumn and the two diagonals all add up to the same number.

If a magic square is filled with numbers in AP starting with $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and common difference $d \in \mathbb{N}$ what is the value of this common sum?

I am thinking that it is just a sum of the AP given? I mean $$\frac{N}{2}[2a+(N-1)d]$$ Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s$ be the common sum. Then each row sums to $s$, and there are $N$ rows, so the sum of all the numbers in the square is $Ns$. That is,

$$\frac{N^2}2\Big(2a+(N^2-1)d\Big)=Ns\;,$$

and $$s=\frac{N}2\Big(2a+(N^2-1)d\Big)\;.$$

(Note that you miscounted the number of terms in the sequence when you wrote down your expression for the sum.)

Comment: I dont understand why you have written $(N^2-1)$, as total number of entries $N^2$ thatswhy?

Comment: @Flute: Yes: the arithmetic progression has $N^2$ terms, so if $a$ is the first term and $d$ the common difference, the last term is $a+(N^2-1)d$.

Comment: @Flute: You’re welcome.